# Expression for a person who cares too much what other people think about him

Tags: idiom-requests, pejorative-language, phrase-requests

Is there an idiom or an expression to describe a person who cares too much what other people think about him?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364461/word-that-means-to-constantly-being-worried-by-ones-appearance

Comment: Without considering his/her opinion on himself/herself?

Comment: hypersensitive, perhaps

Answer (score 1):

frequently used idiom:  ***thin-skinned***

Fig. easily upset or hurt; sensitive. (The opposite of thick-skinned. Typically: be ~; become ~; grow ~.) You'll have to handle Mary's mother carefully. She's very thin-skinned.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thin-skinned

Answer (score 1):

In psychology, such a person is referred to as a **fragile narcissist**

See https://thenarcissisticlife.com/fragile-narcissism/ for a further description and explanation.